# How to set up multiple nested queries used Promise (Node, PG)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise, pg

I need to find a way to correctly set up a Promise for a nested query containing multiple queries. Here is a sample:

```
var results = [];

client.query("SELECT table_1_id AS id FROM table_1", (table_1_error, table_1_data) => {

    client.query("SELECT table_2_id AS id FROM table_2 WHERE table_1_id = " + table_1_data.rows[0].id, (table_2_error, table_2_data) => {

        table_2_data.rows.forEach(function(table_2_row) {

            client.query("SELECT table_3_id AS id FROM table_3_id WHERE table_2_id = " + table_2_row.id, (table_3_error, table_3_data) => {

                table_3_data.rows.forEach(function(table_3_row) {

                    client.query("SELECT table_4_id AS id FROM table_4_id WHERE table_3_id = " + table_3_row.id, (table_4_error, table_4_data) => {

                        results.push({"table_1_id": table_1_data.rows[0].id, "table_2_id": table_2_row.id, "table_3_id": table_3_row.id, "table_4_id": table_4_row.id});

                    });

                });

             });

        });

    });

});

//code below needs to wait until the above is complete
```

I'm using the PG node module to execute these queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PG supports promises directly, you can use promises and `async/await` to do it like this:

```
async function getResults() {
    let results = [];
    let table_1_data = await client.query("SELECT table_1_id AS id FROM table_1");
    let table_2_data = await client.query("SELECT table_2_id AS id FROM table_2 WHERE table_1_id = " + table_1_data.rows[0].id);
    for (let table_2_row of table_2_data.rows) {
        let table_3_data = await client.query("SELECT table_3_id AS id FROM table_3_id WHERE table_2_id = " + table_2_row.id);
        for (let table_3_row of table_3_data.rows) {
            let table_4_data = client.query("SELECT table_4_id AS id FROM table_4_id WHERE table_3_id = " + table_3_row.id);
            results.push({
                "table_1_id": table_1_data.rows[0].id,
                "table_2_id": table_2_row.id,
                "table_3_id": table_3_row.id,
                "table_4_id": table_4_data.id
            });
        }
    }
    return results;
}

getResults().then(results => {
    // process results here
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note that as with all asynchronous operations in node.js, `getResults()` does not block until done (it immediately returns a promise) so you have to process the result inside the `.then()` callback.

---

Note: Heavily nested multi-step requests like this imply that either a better structuring of the data in the database or queries that carry out more than one step in one query are probably recommended.

Note: Your code (which appears to perhaps be pseudo-code) refers to `table_4_row.id` when it pushes the result into the array, but there is no variable in your code called `table_4_row`.  I assumed you meant `table_4_data.id`, but you will have to fix that to whatever it is supposed to be.

Note: This structure assumes that you want to abort the operation on any error and it will reject the promise with that error.  If you want different internal error handling (such as skipping or ignoring errors), you would have to define what you want that to be.  You can catch errors from `await` with `try/catch` to introduce custom error handling.

Comment: Thank for sharing this, it was exactly what I was looking for. It has given me a more clear understanding of how to structure an async function.

Note: The data has lots of many to many relationship tables I assume hence the nested queries. And yes this was just pseudo-code, I have taken the general idea of your answer and adapted this to the context I was after.

Comment: Note  that this would be quite inefficient in practice. This whole thing could be replaced with a single JSON query.

Comment: @vitaly-t - My answer already includes a note about that.  The OP's code is pseudo code to just understand how to sequence things.